# Storing a list to another list

Tags: java

If I had the following declaration of the list:

```
List< Integer> b = new ArrayList< Integer>();
```

and

```
List< HashSet < Integer>> c = new ArrayList< HashSet< Integer>>();
```

I was wondering how would I be able to add `b` to `c`?

I've tried `c.add(b);` 
but this doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: not at all. `c` holds (many) HashSets of Integers, `b` just Integers

Comment: They are different types, it is not possible. Compiler complains. Generics are for the purpose of making sure compile time compatibility.

Comment: In this case, what does it mean to add b to c?  Did you want to have a HashSet<List<Integer>> for c instead?  As it is, c is a list of sets of integers, so all you can add to it are sets of integers, not lists of integers.

Comment: I think it is better to sit back and think what you really want there, you want to directly add to integers (or) create a set and add it?

Comment: You have c as a List containing HashSets. b is a List, not a HashSet. Do you want c to be a List containing Lists or a HashSet containing lists? Or do you want b to be a HashSet?

Comment: Then 1) don't use generics. 2) You need to make sure runtime compatibility while reading data from List. You will be sacrificing compile time check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add a `HashSet` of integers to a list of integers. They're two different datatypes. If you would have a `HashSet` of integers instead of a List of integers, then you would be able to add them to your list.

like this:

```
HashSet< Integer> b = new HashSet< Integer>();
List< HashSet < Integer>> c = new ArrayList< HashSet< Integer>>();
c.add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `c` as a list of *sets* (specifically "hash-sets"), not a list of *lists*; so it doesn't make sense to add a list to it. If you want `c` to be a list of *lists*, you can write:

```
List<List<Integer>> c = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

c.add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using generics and defining that `b` will be a list of `Integers` and `c` will be a list of `HashSet`s that contain `Integers`, so no, you cannot add `b` to `c`

Answer (score 1):

yes, because first list of integers the second one list of hashsets of integers
There are ywo variants,

- Add all values from first list to first value of secod list like that

> ```
> HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet();
> hs.addAll(b);
> c.add(hs);
> ```

- create new instances of HashSet for each value from first list and put one value from first list , for this solution use loop through first list

> ```
>  for (Integer value: b){
>      c.add(new HashSet<Integer>(){{add(value);}};);
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `HashSet` and set elements from `b` to it and then add the HashSet to `c` as below:

```
    List< Integer> b = new ArrayList< Integer>();
    List< HashSet < Integer>> c = new ArrayList< HashSet< Integer>>();
    HashSet < Integer> b1= new HashSet<Integer>();
    b1.addAll(b);
    c.add(b1);
```